# With Leap Motion Controller in Unity, the virtual hands during interaction with objects penetrates the object. Is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, leap-motion

The Rigged Hands provided by Leap Motion is used in this project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://blog.leapmotion.com/interaction-sprint-exploring-the-hand-object-boundary/) might help you to think about how you manage interactions between virtual hands and object. Rather than preventing penetration another method is to look at how you can use the penetration to show the user what is happening and increase the sense of presence.